# Changing tab order in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Report is used to generate PDFs in the system. We would like to know if there are any possibility to add Tab Order in the report. So that the fields in a report can be numbered to denote the order the cursor has to move on Tab press. Since the reading order of the PDF generated depends on the order of the fields placed in the rpt file, setting Tab Order will help in reordering the fields so that the PDF is properly read from top to bottom.

Comment: please refer to following link https://scn.sap.com/thread/3799975